# Content edit made by Admin is not showing for unauthenticated user in Drupal

Tags: drupal, pantheon

Thank you all for help in advance!

Beforehand, I am almost new to Drupal. The admin role made some edits to the content of a post in Drupal site hosted on Pantheon, however that specific edit is not showing to the unauthenticated user.

These are suggestions what I found on web that were not helpful so far:

- I cleared the cache from Pantheon live panel,
- the cache for the view is disabled,
- I cleared all the caches from Performance section as well.

I searched a lot more, not sure what else can be the issue.

Please let me know what else I can do?

Comment: maybe a revision and/or permissions problem ? don't have a preicse answer but I'd take a look to the permissions page (admin/people/permissions), and check if there is a validation step in your content editing workflow (maybe admin can see his own revision, not unauthenticated users, maybe revision must be approved...)

Comment: It was fixed overnight, nothing at my side, I believe that was just the Pantheon(Hosting Company) caching system making the trouble. They have the option to clear the cache manually, but I think either it works partially or not at all. My colleague mentioned changes were taking effect immediately in the past; however, it`s not for now either due to their internal upgrades or some other reasons. Thanks anyway.